# Solution of a nonlinear ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE$$-vU'=2(UU''+(U')^2),$$ where $v$ is a constant. I can see that the right hand side is $(U^2)''$ but is this useful.

Comment: What is $v$? The independent variable?

Comment: $v$ is the variable or some constant?

Comment: see the edit it's a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have
$$-vU' = (U^2)'',$$ integrate this once and get
$$-vU + C = (U^2)',$$ this is a regular first order ODE which you can solve
$$-vU + C = 2UU'\\
U' = \frac{1}{2}(-v + \frac{C}{U}).
$$
by integrating
$$\int \frac{2dU}{-v + \frac{C}{U}} = \int 1 dt$$
if $t$ is your variable. You get
$$t = -\frac{1}{v^2}(C\log(C - vU) + vU)+D$$
for constants $C$ and $D$. The inverse is of course a pain, but still, $U$ is defined in the equation above.